# When asking questions, suggest to provide vital information

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, android

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [auto-smell the phrase “it doesn't work” and ask user if enough info given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/auto-smell-the-phrase-it-doesnt-work-and-ask-user-if-enough-info-given)
>   [Add requirements for a tag (maybe a template?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16843/add-requirements-for-a-tag-maybe-a-template)

This is happening over and over again. People say that their **Android** application *isn't working*, crashing etc, and not providing us with vital information, error from **LogCat**. Without it debugging is slow and annoying since we don't know where to start.

So what i suggest is, that when someone uses *Android* as a tag, he would be *advised* to provide LogCat information if he is asking about 'broken' code, or at least tell where it is crashing.

Example of such case: [Android Unknown Application Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617191/android-unknown-application-crash)

Always the same comments come:

> "How about letting us see the crash log so we can at least have a clue where to look? – >Paul.s"

and

> "'adb logcat' is your friend. It will show you a stack trace, pointing at the exact line and >source file that caused the crash. – kisplit"

Answer (score 4):

It's a good idea,and  [if it could be effectively implemented] should be generalised to **all** questions.

Time and time again, questions are asked with insufficient information provided.

Comment: I disagree, this kind of detection doesn't work. The users that are most in need of targeting won't read the prompts anyway.

Comment: @cody the "if question is in a given tag, use this template or run these checks" has a *bit* more merit, at least.. see dupe I closed of, and related.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by thinking about ways to improve the [Android Tag Wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)

The Tag Wiki is your community's FAQ page.  At the moment, there are a lot of links in there pointing to various Android resources, but not much in the way of guidance for new users about how to ask questions properly.

Once the tag wiki includes helpful tips about how to ask good questions, you can then point new users to the Tag Wiki for the needed guidance.

Beyond that, always vote to close as "Not a Real Question" questions that do not contain sufficient information to be answerable.  The OP always has the opportunity to improve the question and ask that it be reopened.

Comment: fantastic point about improving the tag wiki, now it is on us to make it more visible. We have some stuff in the works...

Answer (score 0):

@Robert, I agree with your guidance, but I think the OP wishes is for this information to be encountered before posting, not *after being lambasted to check the tag-wiki*.  That said, the [Andriod tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) could use a set of suggested inclusions - logcat, etc.

**Further**, (and the reason why this is an answer / not a comment) is that I think this sort of information would be most useful for **Tag Collisions**: When certain tags appear *together* the user could be provided with an auto-generated **2nd** entry box below the entered question where it requests logcat output, stack traces, or perhaps even system specific information <-- more specific to the niche sites like [AskUbuntu]. This sort of information, relevant to [android](/questions/tagged/android) **+** [memory-leaks](/questions/tagged/memory-leaks), may not make sense for either tag-wiki independently.

I have a suspicion that the server backend to sense when certain tag collisions occur *probably already exists* to catch extremely low-quality questions (though I have little basis for this hunch).  **Note**: I'm not suggesting a second, separate frame for each such question, merely a second request for user input (requiring 20 characters or something) which would be auto-appended to the original question and perhaps offset with a header: *accompanying information*.  Lastly, this could be implemented using the same system as tag synonyms.